# Why isn't the contentwraphere div fully showing?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have no idea why but the contentherewrap div does not show fully when you click ‘Returning Quality Services’ in firefox, chrome  and safari but does show in IE and opera

http://www.nswnationals.org.au/index.php/achievements/

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue with height of div with class `contentherewrap`. Height of this div is 1297px but height of its parent is 580px.

Fix the height appropriately and problem should be fixed.

**Note:** Ideally you should not fix the height of a div and let it take any height as per the volume of its contents unless you have some specific reason to set the height to certain pixels or to certain percentage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you - i added some code to dynamically resize .blogachievements and that fixed it.